# 正規表現で複数行のテキストから最後のイコールから文字を取り出す方法

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

JavaScriptで出力フォームからイコールを含むものが複数行あり、マッチした最後だけ取り出したいのですが、正規表現一行でできる方法はありますか？以下の方法以外に色々試しましたがうまくいきません。

以下の文字列がtextareaに入っている。\nで改行された3行。イコールの間はスペースがある：
    aaa = 3.14
    bbb = 2.18
    ccc = 1.0e+3

textareaのHTMLでのidはoutput_logなので、そこからテキストを取得してからマッチさせる。

試した方法：
`var output_form = document.getElementById("output_log");`
`var get_result = output_form.value.match(/.*\n.* = .*$/)`

→get_resultはnullなので、配列から指定して取り出すことができない。

欲しいのは最後の行の「1.0e+3」の部分だけ。

Comment: 改行コードを削除してから match を実行すれば良いのではないでしょうか。`var get_result = output_form.value.replace(/\n/g, "").match(/= +([^ ]+)$/)[1];`

Comment: @argus ありがとうございました。動作確認できました。

Comment: 皆さま、回答ありがとうございます。頂いた回答の動作確認は
http://lazynick.github.io/regex_test_20150927.html
で行います。
最後の行に\nが入ってい気づき、それも質問での正規表現マッチしない問題の原因であると気づきました。そのため現時点で頂いた回答で改行あるなしでテストしましたが、結果はあまり変わらないようでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

最後の行の=以降が取得したいのなら、特に\nを意識しなくていいと思います。

```
var output_form = document.getElementById("output_log");
var get_result = output_form.value.match(/([^ =]+)$/)[1];
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。私の意図した形で動作確認できました。改行を意識しないのは思いつきませんでした。シンプルで良いですね。

Answer (score 1):

改行を含む複数行でのマッチの場合は`m`フラグを使用します。
あと、マッチさせるのが目的でなくて最後の「1.0e+3」の部分なのですから`( )`でその部分をくくって部分マッチ部分を取りだします。
例えば以下の様にします。

```
var output_form = document.getElementById("output_log");
var re = /^(.*\n)*.+ = (.+)$/m;

var get_result = "";
if(re.test(output_form.value)){//マッチのテスト
    get_result = RegExp.$2;//$2は、マッチしたカッコの二つ目
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。matchを追加すると動作します。1行で済ますには、配列を指定すれば取れそうな気がします。

Comment: そうですね。部分マッチが２コあるので、`[2]`ですね。